# ReactJS Browser Back button to refresh the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a Search page that is composed of multiple react components. A user will type a keyword to search and see the results, all happens on the same page.

User can come to this page by clicking a search button on home page or to this page directly by typing the URL. URL pattern is `http://example.com/search?q=text`

Here is my page markup

[image]

`<Search>` component will update the redux state and issue required backend calls to get the data on `componentDidMount` lide cycle event.

Component flow:

1. `<Search />` will read the query string and updates redux state which triggers two API calls, one for facets and another for results.
2. `<SearchBox />` component will show this text in the textbox
3. `<Facets />` and `<Results />` display data based on redux state updated by the backend calls.
4. `<CountBar />` displays some aggregated information of the results

After the initial load, User can type a search term in the textbox in `<SearchBox />` and press `enter`. This button click will update the redux state and issues a `history.push("/search?q=test")`. This repeats the process mentioned above and updates the URL. Everything is fine till here.

After couple of searches, if users presses browser back button `<Search />` component is not updating the data based on the query string as `componentDidMount` is not triggered. None of the child component events are triggered. I tried using `componentWillRecieveProps` but this is going into an infinite loop.

One option I can think of is to pass the query string as props to child components (Don't if that helps to avoid this problem) but I need this query string in redux state, as I have few other routes that needs the last searched query string value.

So now I have few questions:

1. What is the best way to handle browser back button in this scenario?
2. Here  component is responsible for updating the query string to redux, Is that a good behavior?
3. I am using React 16.7 and not using React Hooks. Is upgrading to latest version or using Hooks will help in any way?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'd suggest using this library for handling query string/redux state synchronization - https://github.com/Treora/redux-query-sync . If you don't want to use whole package you can take a look into using history.listen callback which you can implement to update your redux state.

Comment: @ŽeljkoHuber How and where should I trigger my action? state change should trigger an action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have missed something when I tried `componentWillReceivePorps` initially. I tried with this and it is working as expected. In this method I am comparing `newprops` with existing props to see if they are different and make API call accordingly. For the first page load `componentDidMount` will make the API call.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps: any){

    let keyword = querystring.parse(this.props.location.search).q;
    let newKeyword = querystring.parse(newProps.location.search).q;

    if(keyword != newKeyword){
      //trigger redux action
    }
  }
```